# Php Parse error unexpected ;

Tags: php, parsing

Hi i have this code in php:

```
    $dt = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $uploadBookFile  = $UPLOAD_DIR_BOOK."/".$dt.basename($_FILES['book']['name'])).".pdf";
    $uploadHomeFile  = $UPLOAD_DIR_HOMEWORK."/".$dt.basename($_FILES['homework']['name'])).".pdf";
```

And i'm getting this error:  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/daltapps/public_html/server/CMS/addlecture/upload.php`. I'm getting this error at the end of $dt

Comment: You forgot closing parenthesis in your `$dt = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`. You need to analyze carefully you code... From both other lines, there are extra closing parenthesis `)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it look like this:

```
    $dt = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

You missed closing bracket and added two extra brackets in next lines. Code should look like this:

```
    $dt = md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $uploadBookFile  = $UPLOAD_DIR_BOOK."/".$dt.basename($_FILES['book']['name']).".pdf";
    $uploadHomeFile  = $UPLOAD_DIR_HOMEWORK."/".$dt.basename($_FILES['homework']['name']).".pdf";
```

Comment: Does not work @IvanSelivanov, now i just get this error 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/daltapps/public_html/server/CMS/addlecture/upload.php

At this line: $uploadBookFile  = $UPLOAD_DIR_BOOK."/".$dt.basename($_FILES['book']['name'])).".pdf";

Comment: Yes. There are two extra brackets in following lines, after $_FILES['book']['name'])). It should be like  $uploadBookFile = $UPLOAD_DIR_BOOK."/".$dt.basename($_FILES['book']['name']).".pdf